# Getting mySQL stored procedure results in another stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I need an example of a stored procedure that uses the results of two another stored procedures (or even just one) where the results are used as tables in the combining stored procedure. I could likely take it from there.

examples on web (multiple sites) and details at php.net are too simplistic.

The basic issue can be seen here:

```
SELECT ttd.person_id, weight, min(test_date)
FROM (
  CALL get_team_member_body_stats(1) AS tbs,   
  CALL get_team_member_first_last_test_date(1) AS ttd
  WHERE tbs.person_id = ttd.person_id
  AND (tbs.test_date = ttd.first_test OR tbs.test_date = ttd.last_test)
  GROUP BY ttd.person_id;
END
```

Thanks for any help. I've beat my head against this for several hours yesterday and today in online searching and experimenting.

Details:

## Table 1

stored procedure get_team_member_body_stats(IN team_id INT) works over 5 tables (person, team, person_team, body_stats, person_body_stats) and produces:

```
person_id | body_stats_id | weight | test_date |   
  2         2               200      2011-01-01  
  4         3               250      2011-01-01  
  1         5               145      2011-03-01 
  2         6               210.4    2011-03-01 
  5         7               290      2011-03-01 
  1         8               140      2011-04-01 
  1         9               135      2011-05-01 
  4         11              245      2011-05-01
```

## Table 2

stored procedure get_team_member_first_last_test_date(IN team_id INT) works over the same tables and produces:

```
person_id | first_test | last_test

1           2011-03-01   2011-05-01
2           2011-01-01   2011-03-01
4           2011-01-01   2011-05-01
5           2011-03-01   2011-03-01
```

Goal is to join these and produce:

## Table 3

```
person_id | first_weight | last_weight

1           145            135
2           200            210.4 
4           250            245
5           290            290
```

Thanks

Comment: I think the summary is pretty good, +1 for that. I would consider removing the rest if I were you (as it's not easy to understand)

Comment: Problem:  1. sp1 (IN team_id INT) returns "table" of person_id, weight, test_date.  2. sp2 (IN team_id INT) returns "table" of person_id, start_test, last_test  3. Trying to produce sp3 (IN team_id INT) that will join these and return "table" of person_id, weight, start_date.

Comment: As to the question (I actually had to look at the original), at first sight, it looks to me like what you need can be accomplished without stored procedures at all. How many tables are involved? Perhaps you can post <ahum> another question with the relevant tables and the results you expect.

Comment: @Lieven, bad idea. Michelle, make any relevant edits to this question, please.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta - it would be an entirely different question to this one (this one can't be solved robustly). I believe OP is asking this question with a specific solution already in mind while he/she should leave that solution out of the question (there's a term for that but it slips my mind for now). Anyway, with all the comments this question already has attrackted, OP might as wel just delete this and post a new one.

Comment: See details in my edit for the simplification of the problem.  I might learn to pose a question by the end of this. :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears (per this community and because I couldn't find any examples of stored procedures using result sets from other stored procedures as tables in new select tables)  that mysql either doesn't support this or that it is ridiculously hard to do what I hoped to do.

So rather than calling stored procedures I copied the queries into this final procedure.

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_team_stats_change`(
        IN team_id INT
    )
    BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(start_weight) AS start_weight, 
        SUM(start_body_fat) AS start_body_fat, 
        SUM(current_weight) AS current_weight,
        SUM(current_body_fat) AS current_body_fat,
        SUM(weight_change) AS weight_change, 
        SUM(body_fat_change) AS body_fat_change FROM (
    SELECT ls.person_id, 
        fs.weight AS start_weight, fs.body_fat AS start_body_fat, 
        ls.weight AS current_weight, ls.body_fat AS current_body_fat,
        fs.weight - ls.weight AS weight_change, fs.body_fat - ls.body_fat AS body_fat_change
    FROM
    (SELECT ttd.person_id, bs.weight, bs.body_fat, bs.test_date
    FROM body_stats AS bs
    JOIN
        ((SELECT pbs.person_id,  min(bs.test_date)  AS first_test, max(bs.test_date) AS last_test   
        FROM body_stats AS bs,
            person_body_stats AS pbs,
            team_member AS tm,
            team AS t
        WHERE t.team_id = team_id
        AND tm.team_id = t.team_id
        AND tm.person_id = pbs.person_id
        AND pbs.body_stats_id = bs.body_stats_id
        AND tm.start_date  bs.test_date
        AND bs.test_date >= t.starting_date
        GROUP BY person_id) AS ttd,
        person_body_stats AS pbs)
    ON bs.test_date = ttd.first_test 
        AND pbs.person_id = ttd.person_id 
        AND pbs.body_stats_id = bs.body_stats_id) AS fs,

    (SELECT ttd.person_id, bs.weight, bs.body_fat, bs.test_date
    FROM body_stats AS bs
    JOIN
        ((SELECT pbs.person_id,  min(bs.test_date)  AS first_test, max(bs.test_date) AS last_test   
        FROM body_stats AS bs,
            person_body_stats AS pbs,
            team_member AS tm,
            team AS t
        WHERE t.team_id = team_id
        AND tm.team_id = t.team_id
        AND tm.person_id = pbs.person_id
        AND pbs.body_stats_id = bs.body_stats_id
        AND tm.start_date  bs.test_date
        AND bs.test_date >= t.starting_date
        GROUP BY person_id) AS ttd,
        person_body_stats AS pbs)
    ON bs.test_date = ttd.last_test 
        AND pbs.person_id = ttd.person_id 
        AND pbs.body_stats_id = bs.body_stats_id) AS ls
        WHERE ls.person_id = fs.person_id
       ) AS delta;
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how easily you can get these results from 5 tables incorporated into a temporary table or a view but essentially, following should do the same as what you are currently trying to using 3 stored procedures for.

```
SELECT person_id
       , (SELECT weight 
          FROM   FiveTablesResult 
          WHERE  person_id = ftr.person_id 
                 AND test_date = (SELECT MIN(test_date) 
                                  FROM   FiveTablesResult 
                                  WHERE  person_id = ftr.person_id)
         ) AS first_weight
       , (SELECT weight 
          FROM   FiveTablesResult 
          WHERE  person_id = ftr.person_id 
                 AND test_date = (SELECT MAX(test_date) 
                                  FROM   FiveTablesResult 
                                  WHERE  person_id = ftr.person_id)
         ) AS last_weight
FROM   FiveTablesResult ftr
```

*Note that there is room for optimization but let us first get the correct results returned*

Comment: Thanks. I have stored procedures to produce data for the two pieces you call FiveTablesResult as shown in Table 1 and Table 2 above. How do I replace the placeholder 'FiveTablesResult' with the calls to those stored procedures? ...(SELECT weight FROM (CALL get_team_member_body_stats(person_id)) WHERE ... does not work.

Comment: @Michelle - the problem with your approach is that there is no way (that I'm aware of) to incorporate the results of a stored procedure in a plain select. I still looks to me though that it should be possible to ommit the stored procedures alltogether and retrieve the data you need with a plain select statement but for that to know for sure, we would need to have a schema on how your tables are linked and preferably some testdata and the required results.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the answer is: "this can't be done." Instead I can put the Select statements in php. I didn't want to because it scares the website owner/developer. What I will do is create a library of php functions in separate files and show him how to do an include for just the function he needs to call.  Not ideal but workable.  Or should I look into views as an approach to creating a library of 'functions' that the front-end developer can use?  Thanks again for your consideration of my question(s).

Comment: @Michelle - This can't be done *to my knowledge*, an important distinction. How then this is best solved in PHP is also beyond me. PHP is really not my forte.

Comment: As many hours as I've put into finding an answer - I'd go with "The probability of this being done with stored procedures is tiny." I know how to make it work with PHP so will just do it that way.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just to wrap this up.  I created a stored procedure that doesn't build up from other stored procedures.  Here is what I did: