# Two Stored procedures to linked for the output

Tags: mysql

I have two procedures p1 and p2. My p1 gives me 4 columns output. I want a single column from p1 to be used in p2 procedure in a select query output in where condition. I am using mysql, 
Please suggest it.

Comment: possible duplicates: [use result set of mysql stored procedure in another stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466713/use-result-set-of-mysql-stored-procedure-in-another-stored-procedure), [Getting mySQL stored procedure results in another stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662987/getting-mysql-stored-procedure-results-in-another-stored-procedure)

Comment: Do you want to use srored procedure to use it in SELECT...FROM clause? Please provide more information, show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Run the first store procedure.

Take the column value you want from the result and store it in a variable.

If a valid value available in the variable, Use that variable while calling the second stored procedure.

Comment: Can you tell me how to take the result and store in a variable.

Comment: @hariprasad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466713/use-result-set-of-mysql-stored-procedure-in-another-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$smt[i]=$row['column_name'];
i++;
}
```

Now the column is stored in the array $smt.

Comment: That's some funny-looking `mysql` code.

Comment: please explain me clearly how to use it.